# Get Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product Output on GUI Form

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Hi I'm new to Powershell. I'm looking `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product` output on a GUI Form. 
Thanks in Advance.

Below is the Code, I need to add label to the buttons and assign a function to each button.

> > Label: Uninstall
> >     Function: Uninstall
> >     Start-Process Powershell -verb runas # Load Windows Forms assembly [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") [void][System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles() # Create a GUI $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form $form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(920,500) $form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::Fixed3D $form.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen $dataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView $dataGridView.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(900,400) $button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button $button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,420) $button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25) $button.text = "Uninstall" $form.Controls.Add($button) $form.Controls.Add($dataGridView) # Select appropriate columns $dataGridView.Columns.Insert(0, (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewButtonCell)) $dataGridView.ColumnCount = 8 $dataGridView.ColumnHeadersVisible = $true $dataGridView.Columns[0].Name = "Uninstall" $dataGridView.Columns[1].Name = "Description" $dataGridView.Columns[2].Name = "IdentifyingNumber" $dataGridView.Columns[3].Name = "Name" $dataGridView.Columns[4].Name = "Vendor" $dataGridView.Columns[5].Name = "Version" $dataGridView.Columns[6].Name = "Caption" $dataGridView.Columns[7].Name = "InstallLocation" $dataGridView.Columns[0].width = 40 $dataGridView.Columns[1].width = 200 # Get a list of items <#Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | foreach { $dataGridView.Rows.Add($*.Check,$*.Description,$*.IdentifyingNumber,$*.Name,$*.Vendor,$*.Version,$*.Caption,$*.InstallLocation) | out-null }#> # Refresh function gridClick(){ $rowIndex = $dataGridView.CurrentRow.Index $columnIndex0 = $dataGridView.ColumnIndex+1 $columnIndex1 = $dataGridView.ColumnIndex+2 $columnIndex2 = $dataGridView.ColumnIndex+3 $columnIndex3 = $dataGridView.ColumnIndex+4 $columnIndex5 = $dataGridView.ColumnIndex+5 #Write-Host $rowIndex #Write-Host $columnIndex0 #Write-Host $dataGridView.Rows[$rowIndex].Cells[0].value Write-Host $dataGridView.Rows[$rowIndex].Cells[$columnIndex0].value Write-Host $dataGridView.Rows[$rowIndex].Cells[$columnIndex1].value Write-Host $dataGridView.Rows[$rowIndex].Cells[$columnIndex5].value #$IdentifyNumber = $dataGridView.Rows[$rowIndex].Cells[$ClassKey].value #$Name = $dataGridView.Rows[$rowIndex].Cells[$columnIndex0].value #$classKey = 'IdentifyingNumber=$IdentifyingNumber.value,Name=$Name.value,Version=$Version.value' #Write-Host $classKey #([wmi]”\$server\root\cimv2:Win32_Product.$classKey”).uninstall() } $Uninstall = $dataGridView.Add_CellMouseClick({gridClick}) # Show the form [void]$form.ShowDialog()

Comment: Which Powershell version? Tagging specific version means that solution that worksi *only* on that version is desired. As PS2/3/4 are quite different, tagging all those might not be relevant.

Comment: What kind of GUI form are you looking for, anyway? Would `Out-GridView` be good enough?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Out-Gridview is fair for me but Matt Szadziul ans is what i'm looking for.

Comment: **Never use `Win32_Product`**. You should instead [query the registry directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71575378/powershell-for-software-inventory/71576041#71576041) for inventorying software on Windows. `Win32_Product` will result in integrity checks and repair installations when listing software, which can cause unintended outages or resource contention on systems with other critical applications. Not to mention unscheduled/unplanned changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bit of an overkill but you can always create a customized GUI form and paint the output in a gridview control like this:

```
# Load Windows Forms assembly

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 
[void][System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

# Create a GUI

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(920,500)
$form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::Fixed3D
$form.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen
$dataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$dataGridView.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(900,400)
$button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,420)
$button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
$button.Text = "Refresh"
$form.Controls.Add($button)
$form.Controls.Add($dataGridView)

# Select appropriate columns

$dataGridView.ColumnCount = 7
$dataGridView.ColumnHeadersVisible = $true
$dataGridView.Columns[0].Name = "Description"
$dataGridView.Columns[1].Name = "IdentifyingNumber"
$dataGridView.Columns[2].Name = "Name"
$dataGridView.Columns[3].Name = "Vendor"
$dataGridView.Columns[4].Name = "Version"
$dataGridView.Columns[5].Name = "Caption"
$dataGridView.Columns[6].Name = "InstallLocation"

$dataGridView.Columns[0].width = 240

# Get a list of items

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | foreach {
    $dataGridView.Rows.Add($_.Description,$_.IdentifyingNumber,$_.Name,$_.Vendor,$_.Version,$_.Caption,$_.InstallLocation) | out-null
}

# Refresh

$button.Add_Click({

    $dataGridView.Rows.Clear()

    start-sleep -s 1

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | foreach {
    $dataGridView.Rows.Add($_.Description,$_.IdentifyingNumber,$_.Name,$_.Vendor,$_.Version,$_.Caption,$_.InstallLocation) | out-null
}

})

# Add a cell click function

function cellClick(){
$rowIndex = $dataGridView.CurrentRow.Index
$columnIndex = $dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
$value = $dataGridView.Rows[$rowIndex].Cells[$columnIndex].value
write-host $value
}

$dataGridView.Add_CellMouseClick({cellClick})

# Show the form

[void]$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Hey Matt can you help me to read the individual data from the Grid for the Selected Cells. I've modified the script where I need to select the Item and Uninstall the App. I'm stuck with reading the selected item.

Comment: Hi Deep :) I added a function that retrieves the cell value of the current column and the current row. If you launch the script via ISE, the selected value will be written to the console (variable value). Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this method to see a GUI grid  :

```
gwmi -Class win32_product | Out-GridView
```

and also you can get custom output like XML and CSV and json and other form and use special software for that .